# How to overlay scatterplots in ggplot when one plot has colors defined in its dataframe?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to overlay two scatter plots. Here is the base code:

```r
ggplot() + geom_point(data = df, aes(A, B, color = Cluster), shape=1)  + 
  geom_point(data = as.data.frame(centers), aes(A, B), shape=13, size=7, alpha = 5)
```

This is what the plot looks like: [image]

But when I attempt to add a color to the overlaid cluster centers (those circles with X inside):

```r
ggplot() + geom_point(data = df, aes(A, B, color = Cluster), shape=1)  + 
  geom_point(data = as.data.frame(centers), aes(A, B, color = "red"), shape=13, size=7, alpha = 5)
```

**I get the following error:** "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

Here is a portion of the dataframe I am using to plot the first of two overlays:

```r
> df
              A             B Cluster
1    1.33300195 -1.4524680585       2
2    1.41102294 -0.7889431279       2
3    1.36350553 -1.4437548005       2
4    1.61462300 -0.7145174514       2
5   -0.64722704  0.8449845639       1
6    1.33855918 -0.9161504530       2
7    1.33467865 -2.1513899524       2
8    1.50842550 -0.5170262065       2
9    1.67045671 -0.3644476090       2
10   1.32328373 -1.5496692059       2
```

My theory is that ggplot is interpreting the "Cluster" column of that dataframe as a continuous variable. Is there a way to change it so its discrete? Should I instead use a column of colors as factors? For example: 1 becomes "Blue", 2 becomes "Black"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. No data for `centers` so can not add that to the plot. You are right in the fact that the continuous variable is messing the plot. Instead set it as `factor()` and use `scale_color_manual()` to change the colors. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot() + geom_point(data = df, aes(A, B, color = factor(Cluster),
                                     fill = factor(Cluster)))  + 
  geom_point(data = as.data.frame(centers), aes(A, B, color = "red"),
             shape=13, size=7, alpha = 5)+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('blue','black'))+labs(color='Cluster',fill='Cluster')
```

Output:

[image]

Or keeping the original shape:

```
#Code 2
ggplot() + geom_point(data = df, aes(A, B, color = factor(Cluster)),shape=1)  + 
  geom_point(data = as.data.frame(centers), aes(A, B, color = "red"),
             shape=13, size=7, alpha = 5)+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('blue','black'))+labs(color='Cluster')
```

Output:

[image]